# how to print colored contents into csv file in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++14

I am trying to print a color value into an output doc or some color supported file, I found printing the colored values into a console but it's not applying the file output values, I tried a couple of header files **rang.hpp** and **rlutil.h** but both are useful, but only for printing in the console not for out file.
here is my trying code

```
 #include<iostream>
 #include<fstream>
 using namespace std;

void PrintColoredFile(ofstream& outfile)
{
  outfile<<"red,blue"<<endl; //I don't know how to print coloured values
  outfile<<"This is a red colored message, This is a blue colored message"<<endl;
}

int main()
{
ofstream outFile.open("My_ColouredFile.doc",ios::out);
if(!outFile)
   exit(1);
 PrintColoredFile(outFile);
 return 0;
}
```

It's not a **repeated** question, i tried **everywhere**, but **I didn't find a solution for this problem**. **Please help me**,

Comment: What do you mean by "color value"? Write an RGB value?

Comment: You *don't*. A CSV file is a plain-text file, and as such it can't contain such information.

Comment: And as for why it works with the console, it's because the *terminal program* parses the output you write to handle it (if you use [VT100](http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm) control codes).

Comment: @UnholySheep color value means text with color, Ex:**This text color is black**  like this..

Comment: Have you ever seen a CSV file with colored text like this? As others have already mentioned, CSV is a plain-text format, so I'm not sure where you have seen that it should be possible to color text in it

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, when printing the output file using file streams, i want that printed values with color, instead of default black colored text. i want some different color for the printing values

Comment: I know what you mean, and it's simply not possible. Unless you write the VT100 color codes to the file, and then only display it in a console window that supports those codes. It will not work when importing into Excel for example, your fields will just contain weird characters. Again, CSV is a ***plain text*** format. It contains text, nothing more. If you want color in your files, use another format.

Comment: @ UnholySheep, It's comma separated values, my intention is To printing the output file it may text or csv format, that printed value in color instead of default black color...

Comment: @ Some programmer dude,  i will use another format, can you please provide me what kind of format it is?? and please give some sample program.

Comment: @ Some programmer dude, here my problem is printing the values into color in the output file in c++...

Comment: How are you intending to use this csv file such that you see the colours? Are you just wanting to print it out, or are you going to feed it into another program that can interpret the colour codes you want?

Comment: @ Gem Taylor, my goal is to print an output file(using file streams) and values are in the color, but coincidentally I was chosen CSV format.Just for viewing purpose.I am learning graphics in c++,i interested printing color values in output file.

Answer (score 2):

CSV stands for Comma-separated values. You can't store any color values in a csv-file. It's plain text.

Very often Microsoft Excel is the standard tool for opening csv-files. If you make some text coloured and want to save that csv-file, Excel tells you then that some additional information can't be stored and will be lost.